# Regarding subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find the answer to the following question:

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $x \neq y \in X$. Does there exist $U$ and $V$ open such that $x \in U$ and $y \in V$ such that $\overline{U} \cap \overline{V} = \emptyset$.

I know without the closure it is true using the Hausdorff-ness. But how does it follow with the closure as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the condition you mentioned, is call "completely Hausdorff separation axiom" and is stronger than Hausdorffness.

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Comment: @Bernard, Empty.

Comment: The code is `\varnothing`.

Comment: @Qurultay, But then Hausdorff doesnot imply Completely Hausdorff, right?

Comment: @Topology No, it dosen't. But I don't remember a counterexample for now.

Comment: A space with this property is called an Uryssohn space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot: [the relatively prime integer topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_integer_topology) on $\mathbb{Z}$ is a topology that is Hausdorff but not $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$, which is another name for the separation of points by closed neighbourhoods. More such examples can be found using a query in [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Hausdorff%20%2B%20%7E%24T_%7B2%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%24), which is based on the book "Counterexamples in Topology".